# Product of denominators exceed $n$ in Farey sequence

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation

> Why in the $n$-th Farey sequence the product of the denominators of $2$ adjacent fractions exceed $n$ ($0$ and $1$ are excluded) ?

I have a theorem of Hurwitz which states:

> For every irrational number $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ there exists infinitely many rationals $p/q$, such that
>
> $\lvert\alpha-\frac pq\rvert<\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}q^2}$

and [here](http://www.math.uzh.ch/index.php?file&key1=36443#page=5), in the proof of Corollary $1.6$, if $p/q<\alpha<p'/q'$, then $p/q$ and $p'/q'$ are not in $S$ ?

I know that, if $p/q$ and $p'/q'$ are adjacent then; $\lvert\frac pq-\frac {p'}{q'}\rvert=\frac{1}{qq'}$ so according to the proof $qq'>n$, but why ?

Comment: I will just give here three interesting references (in the first two, the property in question is mentionned): 1) the wonderful book
www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/farey.pdf 
2) A survey paper "The Haros-Farey sequence at two hundred Years" (Cobeli Zaharescu) covering recent developments of the Farey sequence: http://www.emis.de/journals/AUA/acta5 /survey3.ps_pages1-20.pdf and the very pedagogical (student's project ?) paper www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/fareyproject.pdf

Comment: If the answer below was helpful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely misunderstanding what the author writes in the proof of Hurwitz's Theorem.

Specifically, he says, "if $S$ a finite set of rational numbers, then **we can take** $n$ large enough...", etc.

This means that *for the given set of rationals* $S$ (not necessarily a set of Farey fractions) he is considering the Farey sequence with $n$ large enough, so that it holds: $|\gamma-\alpha|>\frac{1}{n}$, for every $\gamma\in S$. In other words, **by construction** he picks suitable $n$, so that the gaps between the terms of the Farey sequence he considers are at most $1/n$.

That's the same as saying, given a finite set of rationals $S$, you can find a Farey sequence which partitions your total interval finer than how the set $S$ does it.

But then, by that very consideration, the gaps between any two successive Farey numbers in his sequence, will be:

$$\left|\frac{p}{q}-\frac{p'}{q'}\right|=\frac{1}{qq'}\lt \frac{1}{n}\lt |\gamma-\alpha|$$

which means of course,

$$qq'>n$$